# How to show scrollToBottom in a ScrollView when user is not at the bottom of screen - React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm developing a chat app in which I have a `ChatScreen`, and suppose the user scrolls up through the chat, now a `scrollToBottom`  button should appear **only if** the user is not at bottom (just like popular chat apps), So I tried the following:

First I tried to detect when the user scrolls in a `ScrollView`, then using the `onScroll` prop `nativeEvent` I detected whether or not the user is **not** at bottom i.e. he/she scrolled up. Then if it is the case, I show the button which should appear in the bottom right corner of the ChatScreen.

Below is the code for my approach. (Is it possible to return a `View` component inside `onScroll` prop if the condition satisfies?)

```js
<ScrollView
  ref={scrollViewRef}
  onScroll={({nativeEvent}) => {
    const isCloseToBottom = nativeEvent.layoutMeasurement.height + nativeEvent.contentOffset.y > nativeEvent.contentSize.height - 30;
    if (!isCloseToBottom) {
      console.log('show scroll to bottom button')
      return (
        <TouchableOpacity style={{position:'absolute', bottom:40, right:10, backgroundColor:'grey'}} onPress={() => scrollViewRef.current.scrollToEnd()}>
          <Icon ... />
        </TouchableOpacity>
      )
    }
  }}
>
...
</ScrollView>
```

So this is what I tried, although when I debug using `console.log('show scroll to bottom button')` as you can see in the code, it gets triggered, but I'm not able to render/see the Button component on the screen. (I tried setting `opacity:1` & `zIndex:1` in the style prop of `<TouchableOpacity />` but still can't see).

What am I doing wrong? Any solution to this problem would be really appreciated.

Comment: While I'm not very familiar with React Native, I don't think you're able to return JSX from an event handler. Where would it render? You'll need [conditionally render](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html) your button in the parent component's return statement.

Comment: @ChrisB. is I'm able to do so using a state, however, it would not be an optimized solution because it will keep setting the state to true inside `if (!isCloseToBottom)`...

Answer (score 0):

Okay, the temporary solution is just create a state and do conditional rendering.
(I think this approach would be not optimum because we would be setting state everytime the user scrolls up or whenever `onScroll` triggers).

```js
const [isScrolling, setIsScrolling] = useState(false);
<ScrollView
  ref={scrollViewRef}
  onScroll={({nativeEvent}) => {
    const isCloseToBottom = nativeEvent.layoutMeasurement.height + nativeEvent.contentOffset.y > nativeEvent.contentSize.height - 30;
    if (!isCloseToBottom) {
      setIsScrolling(true);
    } else setIsScrolling(false);
  }}
>
...
</ScrollView>

{
  isScrolling && // return your component here...
}
```

Comment: You could check it before you set it if you want, but even if you don't, React won't re-render if the state is set to an identical primitive value.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your first render view is always at the bottom. So you could wrap your component with parenthesis and set a conditional first, something like:

```
const [isBottom, setIsBottom] = useState(true)

<>
  <ScrollView
    onScroll={(e) => {handleScrolling(e)}}
  >
    return
  </ScrollView>
  {!isBottom &&
    <Touchable style={{ position: 'absolute', right: 20, bottom: 20}}>
      <Text>Last messages</Text>
    </Touchable>
   }
</>
```

In case you want to add some animation you could use `Animated.View` instead.
Another way to verify if the user is on the bottom is by using the `index` but you'll need to use a `<FlatList/>`. Something like:

```
if (index !== data.lenght -1) {
   setIsBottom(false)
}
```

Pass the value on your `const renderItem = (index) => {}`